# Rails 4: filter objects by custom attributes in show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, filter, navigation

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following models:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
  has_many :comments
end
```

The `post` objects are displayed the `Calendars#Show` view of the calendar they belong to.

Each post has a `:date` custom attribute (distinct from the `:created_at` default attribute).

I want to implement a navigation in the `Calendars#Show` view that will allow me to filter posts by their `:date` and display them month by month:

[image]

I have started implementing this as follows:

In `calendars_controller.rb`, I have:

```
def show
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.calendars.find(params[:id])
    @current_month = params[:month].blank? ? Date.today.month : params[:month].to_i
    @current_year = params[:year].blank? ? Date.today.year : params[:year].to_i
    if @current_month == 13
      @current_month = 1
      @current_year = @current_year + 1
    end
    if @current_month == 0
      @current_month = 12
      @current_year = @current_year - 1
    end
    @posts = @calendar
      .posts
      .includes(:comments)
      .where("Extract(month from date) = ?", @current_month)
      .where("Extract(year from date) = ?", @current_year)
      .order "date DESC"
    # authorize @calendar
  end
```

And in Calendars `show.html.erb` file, I have:

```
<%= link_to '< Previous', calendar_path(@calendar, month: @current_month - 1) %>
<%= "#{Date::MONTHNAMES[@current_month]} #{@current_year}" %>
<%= link_to 'Next >', calendar_path(@calendar, month: @current_month + 1) %>
```

(and then I have a loop to display the relevant posts).

The above code works pretty well for the current year, i.e. I can navigate from month to month and I will get the right posts for each month.

However, when I try to navigate to the previous year (hitting the "< Previous" button a couple of times) or to the next year (hitting the "< Previous" button a couple of times), then two things happen:

[image]

- The month sequence goes from January 2015 to December 2014 to November 2015 (or from December 2015 to January 2016 to February 2015), meaning the @current_year is no longer correct.
- Consequently (this is actually a sign that the query works well), I get the same posts all over again, since, instead of navigating to November 2014, I go to November 2015 and therefore display the post for November 2015 (same problem with February 2016 vs. February 2015).

Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to pass the `@current_year` to the `calendar_path` too. Looks like this condition is always setting 2015 as the current year.

```
@current_year = params[:year].blank? ? Date.today.year : params[:year].to_i
```

The reason because it works with December and January is because you change the current year when the month is `0 or 13`

This should work

```
<%= link_to '< Previous', calendar_path(@calendar, month: @current_month - 1, year: @current_year) %>

<%= link_to 'Next >', calendar_path(@calendar, month: @current_month + 1, year: @current_year) %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You were perfectly correct, both in your identification of the problem and the way to fix it. Everything is working now.